# Transition rate

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fermis-golden-rule

In calculating the transition rate between two levels 1 and 2, most QM textbooks say
$$
\left<\psi_2|[x, H_0]|\psi_1\right> = \left<\psi_2|xH_0 - H_0 x|\psi_1\right> = (E_2-E_1)  \left<\psi_2|x|\psi_1\right>. \tag{1}
$$
Since $H_0\psi_1=E_1\psi_1$, $\left<\psi_2|xH_0|\psi_1\right>= E_1 \left<\psi_2|x|\psi_1\right>$ is straightforward. And Equation (1) implies
$$
\left<\psi_2|H_0x|\psi_1\right> = \int \psi_2^* H_0 x \psi_1 d^3x = E_2\left<\psi_2|x|\psi_1\right>. \tag{2}
$$
Could you explain how you can show Equation (2)?

Comment: You seem to understand how $H_0$ operates on eigenkets. Do you understand how it operates on eigenbras?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to let $H_0$ operate on $\psi_2^*$.
Recall that $H_0$ is a Hermitian operator so $H_0=H_0^*$.

$$
\psi_2^*H_0=(H_0\psi_2)^*=(E_2\psi_2)^*=E_2\psi_2^*
$$

Comment: Great! Thank you!